# Clean XHTML tags

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, xslt

I am required to import XML into a piece of software, the XML I am provided is created by a different bit of software and sent to myself. I would normally go through the XML document and strip out all CDATA tags and then have to find and replace all tags from uppercase to lowercase and remove any STRONG tags or OL tags.

But I have to reorganise the tags to allow it to be imported into the software, for example:

<b>Got some text here<p/>More bold text</b>

this will not import unless I manually go in and change it to

<b>Got some text here</b><p/><b>More bold text</b>

I have looked at HTMLTidy and other such tools which will just strip out the <p/> tag completely. I am in need of keeping the data in its original formatting, if there any way to do this?

Comment: I think it is nigh on impossible to change tags without changing formatting.  <b>Got some text here<p/>More bold text</b>  is valid HTML.  Why isnt it acceptable?

Comment: The system I import it into spits back a lot of errors about unclosed &lt;b> tags. It is a poor tool and causing me a nightmare. I was thinking about going down the Regex route to find any tag within tags and insert a close and open around them. I was just hoping there may have been a solution already out there

Comment: Reading HTML is *really* best done with a HTML parser.  I have been through trying to use RegEx and it is an absolute nightmare.  I dont really know your full case so I cant really say what your doing is wrong but it may save you some time!  I would recommend checking out http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ either way! It isnt foolproof, but it does handle most of the malformed tags, etc. that you find on the web these days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xslt, you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b/text()">
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to an input like

```
<b>Got some text here<p/>More bold text</b>
```

outputs:

```
<b>Got some text here</b><p/><b>More bold text</b>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this works a treat. just a few modifications required to get it to integrate with my current code.